# I am trying to call text from input using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call text that has been added to an input using Angular JS, however in my console log I keep getting undefined.

```
<div ng-controller="favouritesController" class="col-xs-12 favList">
  <input type="text" ng-model="newFav" ng-keyup= "add($event)" class="col-xs-12 FavInput" placeholder="Add A Favourite">
  <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="weatherList in weatherLists" class="col-xs-12">
  <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">{{weatherList._id + ' / ' + weatherList.place}}</span>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
    <button type="button" name="button" class="deleFav" ng-click="delete(weatherList)">Delete</button>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" ng-model="serverip"/>
      <button ng-click="save(serverip)">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

js code

```
myApp.controller('favouritesController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $route, $location) {
 $scope.save = function(){
  console.log($scope.serverip)
 }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the parameter to the `save` function (and your definition of `save` doesn't include it).
Change the button to:

```
      <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
```

Or either accept the parameter in the function declaration:

```
$scope.save = function(serverip){
 console.log(serverip)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat creates a new scope, inheriting from the scope above it. You are assigning serverip to this newly created scope. Thus, $scope in the favouritesController's context has no record of this. You should accept a parameter in your save function and log that (as you are passing this function the argument, anyways.)

Edit:
or, as an alternative... Expose a property that will be inherited by ng-repeat:

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('favouritesController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $route, $location) {
 $scope.ip = { serverip:'' };
 $scope.save = function(){
  console.log($scope.ip.serverip)
 }
});
```

Template

```
<div ng-controller="favouritesController" class="col-xs-12 favList">
  <input type="text" ng-model="newFav" ng-keyup= "add($event)" class="col-xs-12 FavInput" placeholder="Add A Favourite">
  <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="weatherList in weatherLists" class="col-xs-12">
  <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">{{weatherList._id + ' / ' + weatherList.place}}</span>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
    <button type="button" name="button" class="deleFav" ng-click="delete(weatherList)">Delete</button>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" ng-model="ip.serverip"/>
      <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```